# Gente tengo este problema para resolver en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Debés crear una función llamada `nuevoArreglo` que reciba un número como parámetro y que devuelva un nuevo arreglo con tantos elementos como el número que le hayas pasado. Ejemplo:

- `nuevoArreglo(5)` debe retornar `[1,2,3,4,5]`,
- `nuevoArreglo(10)` debe retornar `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Y mas o menos tengo esto pensado

```
let nuevoArreglo = []

console.log(nuevoArreglo.length)
```

voy bien?? me falta algo??

Comment: Mira [ask] para tener un poco más claro el formato que debe seguir tu pregunta. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar formato al código para que se vea *iluminado*. Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla. Respecto a tu pregunta, lo que te falta es agregar los elementos al arreglo, si quieres algo sencillo puedes usar un bucle for y asignar el valor `i` a la posición `nuevoArreglo[i]`.

Comment: Qué valor te imprime en consola? Es el valor esperado?

Answer (score 1):

Empezabas bien, tienes que hacer una variable para crear el array, en tu caso: `let nuevoArreglo = []`.

despues, si haces un length del array (arreglo) sin haber metido nada, dará 0 como resultado, tienes que meterle objetos dentro. ¿Cómo? con `nuevoArreglo.push(variable)`.

Para eso cogemos cualquier numero, el que tu quieras, en mi caso te voy a poner un ejemplo con prompt, iniciamos un bucle for, con una salida del bucle de ese mismo numero, y en cada iteración del for hacemos push del objeto en cuestión:

```js
let ary = [];//inicias un nuevo array (arreglo)

    let num = prompt('Escribe un numero');//pides un numero por le prompt
        while(!num || isNaN(num)){//haces un bucle para pedir un numero
            num = prompt('Escribe un numero');//y si no es un numero, te pide de nuevo el prompt
        }

    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++){//inicias un bucle for
        ary.push(i);//en cada iteracion del bucle haces un push de i (valor que cambia) al array
    }

    console.log(ary);//console los del array
```